# based on the record type picklist values need to be controlled

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two record types in my application rt1 and rt2, 
two fields picklist 1 (controlling field) values(1,2,3,4) and picklist 2(dependent field) values(A,B,C,D)

when i select rt1 record type i should see only (1,2) vlaues in picklist1,

when i select rt2 record type i should see only (2,3,4) vlaues in picklist1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. In setup go to the object and select the record type.
When you click on the record type, you will have an option 'Picklists Available for Editing' and here u can select 'Test' field and select/unselect picklist values.

I assume test is a picklist field in above answer

[image]